# Google Appengine Deployment Security Woes

Tags: google-app-engine

We are having trouble deploying our Google Appengine application.  We get the following error message
from the indicated deployment command at the Unix shell prompt.

```
/home/leffstudent/appengine/bin/appcfg.sh update  ~/u3/web/war -p proxy.wiu.edu:8080
```

The following URL can be used to authenticate:

```
 https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&client_id=550516889912.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
Attempting to open it in your browser now.

Unable to open browser. Please open the URL above and copy the resulting code.
Please enter code:
```

There is no browser on this computer, a Linux virtual machine, used as the programming opportunity for the School of
Computer Sciences.  We simply use `putty` to log in.
I cut and pasted the address and entered into Chrome into the computer that has run putty.  I get the code in that browser.  I cut that and tried to paste it back
into the browser. NO luck.

I get

```
"java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused"
```

(This has been difficult because this Putty does not seem to have menu items for cut and paste.)

I tried about seven times.  Several times, I also tried simply typing the code in carefully.  No luck.

The graduate student on the project also tried themselves--no luck!

Thanks for any insight.  In particular, it seems I should I ask the system administrator who set up the disk slice with our School of Computer Sciences'
server for a "browser." What should I specifically ask for?  I did not see any documentation of what the google appcfg.sh program is doing when it tries to "open it in your browser now."

We have a project on which five people have worked over several year time frame that is dead in the water because we can no longer
deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the code isn't working - it should. As a work-around why not:

1. push the code to a git repo (e.g. bitbucket)
2. pull it to a machine that does have a browser
3. Set up the browser-machine to run GCloud under the account you're hoping to authenticate with
4. Deploy from there